# Standard Brownian motion, Markov Property of BM

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I have the following proposition in my textbook:

> Let B be a standard BM. Then, whenever the integral exists, $$E[h(B_{t+s} | \mathcal{F}_s ] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} h(y)p(t;B_s,y)dy  =E^{B_s}[h(B_t)].$$

My question is, what is the transition probability density function $ p(t;x,y)$?

I know that for a standard Brownian motion,

$$ p(t;x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \text{exp}\big(-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2t} \big)$$

But I'm not sure what the arguments t, x and y is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose $(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is the natural filtration of the Brownian motion. In such case, we know that $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$ for all $s<t$; and of course $B_s$ is $\mathscr{F}_s$-measurable. We have (standard assumption: $h$ is measurable and bounded)
$$\begin{aligned}E[h(B_t)|\mathscr{F}_s]&=E[h(B_t-B_s+B_s)|\mathscr{F}_s]=\\&=E[h(B_t-B_s+b)]|_{b=B_s}=\\
&=E[h(B_{t-s}+b)]|_{b=B_s}
\end{aligned}$$
where the last equality follows from $B_t-B_s\sim B_{t-s}$. Also $E[h(B_t)|\mathscr{F}_s]=E[h(B_t)|B_s]$ by the same reasoning (recall: $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $B_s-B_0=B_s$ by properties of Brownian motion) so
$$\begin{aligned}E[h(B_t)|B_s=b]&=E[h(B_{t-s}+b)]=\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}h(x+b)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t-s)}}\exp\bigg(-\frac{x^2}{2(t-s)}\bigg)dx=\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}h(y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t-s)}}\exp\bigg(-\frac{(y-b)^2}{2(t-s)}\bigg)dy
\end{aligned}$$